# How can I group a column based off of a list of string patterns in R?

Tags: r, list, if-statement, sapply, grepl

I have a data frame that has a column of strings like the below:

```
String_Column      Rating
Greenyy             1
BigGREENglow        2
BLUEBERRY           8
Shiny Emeralds      3
Sky Blue            3
Skyblue             6 
CERULEAN            2
Blueish Green       5
BLOO                3
```

I want to create groupings for these values, so if it has a word synonymous with green or contains any variation of the word green, I want to group it as "Green". The same for blue.

So I would like the above to look like this:

```
String_Column     Grouping      Rating
Greenyy           Green         1
BigGREENglow      Green         2 
BLUEBERRY         Blue          8
Shiny Emeralds    Green         3
Sky Blue          Blue          3
Skyblue           Blue          6
CERULEAN          Blue          2
Blueish Green     Green         5  
BLOO              Not Found     3
```

I created a Blue list and a Green list, full of words associated with each.

```
Blue_List <- c("Blue", "BLUE", "blue", "Cerulean" , "CERULEAN", "cerulean" , "Sapphire", "sapphire" , "SAPPHIRE")

Green_List <- c("Green", "GREEN", "green", "Chartreuse", "CHARTREUSE", "chartreuse", "Emerald", "emerald", "EMERALD")
```

I want to then group each string as either Blue or Green based on whether it is in this list.
And add this column to the dataframe. If the value isn't contained in the list, return "Not Found"

I have been able to do this using,

```
    DF$Grouping<-ifelse(grepl("TRUE",sapply(DF$String_Column, grepl, Green_List,ignore.case=TRUE, simplify=FALSE)),  "Green" ,
    grepl("TRUE",sapply(DF$String_Column, grepl, Blue_List,ignore.case=TRUE, simplify=FALSE)),"Blue" ,"Not Found")
```

However, I need to preserve the order of the grouping, and I don't know how to do this.
For the example of "Blueish Green", I want this to be categorized as Green, but instead it will be put into the Blue grouping when the else clause is read.

I suppose I can reorder the ifelse to have "Blue" first, but the actual dataset is a bit more complicated than what I shared, and I ultimately want to perform each "else" to a subset of the dataset where there wasn't a prior grouping.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R method. I'm going to reduce the lists since we can use `ignore.case=TRUE`, but that isn't strictly required: if case is important, then remove that component. The only thing I'm really relying on is that the first element of each is relevant (and the name will be gleaned from it).

```r
tmpstr <- Reduce(function(s, lst) gsub(paste0("(", paste(lst, collapse = "|"), ")"), lst[1], s, ignore.case = TRUE),
                 list(Blue_List, Green_List), init = dat$String_Column)
tmpcolors <- regmatches(tmpstr,
                        gregexpr(paste0("(", paste(Blue_List[1], Green_List[1], sep = "|"), ")"),
                                 tmpstr, ignore.case = TRUE))
tmpcolors <- replace(tmpcolors, sapply(tmpcolors, Negate(length)), NA_character_)
tmpcolors <- sapply(tmpcolors, tail, n = 1)
tmpcolors[ is.na(tmpcolors) ] <- "Not Found"
dat$Grouping <- tmpcolors
dat
#      String_Column Rating  Grouping
# 1 Greenyy               1     Green
# 2 BigGREENglow          2     Green
# 3 BLUEBERRY             8      Blue
# 4 Shiny Emeralds        3     Green
# 5 Sky Blue              3      Blue
# 6 Skyblue               6      Blue
# 7 CERULEAN              2      Blue
# 8 Blueish Green         5     Green
# 9 BLOO                  3 Not Found
```

In fact, if you have more than two color lists, you can simply provide a list of arbitrary collections of colors:

```r
Color_Lists <- list(
  c("Blue", "cerulean" , "sapphire"),
  c("Green", "chartreuse", "emerald")
)
tmpstr <- Reduce(function(s, lst) gsub(paste0("(", paste(lst, collapse = "|"), ")"), lst[1], s, ignore.case = TRUE),
                 Color_Lists, init = dat$String_Column)
tmpcolors <- regmatches(tmpstr,
                        gregexpr(paste0("(", paste0(sapply(Color_Lists, `[[`, 1), collapse = "|"), ")"),
                                 tmpstr, ignore.case = TRUE))
tmpcolors <- replace(tmpcolors, sapply(tmpcolors, Negate(length)), NA_character_)
tmpcolors <- sapply(tmpcolors, tail, n = 1)
tmpcolors[ is.na(tmpcolors) ] <- "Not Found"
dat$Grouping <- tmpcolors
```

---

Data:

The assumption to get "green" from "blueish green" is that it's the last color referenced. If you have rules more complex than "mentioned last", then ... perhaps this won't work perfectly.

```r
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, sep="|", text="
String_Column   |   Rating
Greenyy         |    1
BigGREENglow    |    2
BLUEBERRY       |    8
Shiny Emeralds  |    3
Sky Blue        |    3
Skyblue         |    6 
CERULEAN        |    2
Blueish Green   |    5
BLOO            |    3")

Blue_List <- c("Blue", "cerulean" , "sapphire")
Green_List <- c("Green", "chartreuse", "emerald")
```

Answer (score 0):

hope you can use this

```
#data
string_Column <- c("Greenyy","BigGREENglow","BLUEBERRY","Shiny Emeralds","Sky Blue","Skyblue","CERULEAN","Blueish Green","BLOO")
Rating <- c(1,2,8,3,3,6,2,5,3)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(string_Column,Rating))

#green and blue vector
Blue_List <- c("Blue", "BLUE", "blue", "Cerulean" , "CERULEAN", "cerulean" , "Sapphire", "sapphire" , "SAPPHIRE")
Green_List <- c("Green", "GREEN", "green", "Chartreuse", "CHARTREUSE", "chartreuse", "Emerald", "emerald", "EMERALD")


#applied function
test <- function(x) {
  if(grepl(paste(Green_List,collapse = "|"), x[1])){
    return("Green")
  }
  if(grepl(paste(Blue_List,collapse = "|"), x[1])){
    return("Blue")
  }
  return("none")
}

#save the new vector to dataframe
df$group <- unlist(apply(df, MARGIN = 1, test))
```

Output:

```
string_Column  Rating   group
1   Greenyy         1   Green
2   BigGREENglow    2   Green
3   BLUEBERRY       8   Blue
4   Shiny Emeralds  3   Green
5   Sky Blue        3   Blue
6   Skyblue         6   Blue
7   CERULEAN        2   Blue
8   Blueish Green   5   Green
9   BLOO            3   none
```